# Discussion and participation in other forums

Tags: discussion

I posted a question in another forum recently of stack exchange (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), and the level of participation surprised me. I was kinda jealous and wanted to see the same with our group, what makes multiple users to participate in any given discussion. Is there a lag in our community (or) is it only me who feels that new users are jumping in and becoming dormant as soon as their queries are resolved?

What is so different between salesforce.stackexchange and other stackexchange forums, is it the concentration of people who are working on a specific technology (or) is it the focus area on which the questions being asked are so popular (or) some kind of spl SEO the forums have ( I would believe not) turning traffic to the forums always (or) is it the marketing and promotions like windows8 forums did by offering freebies that attracts active participants ?

I am too aware of the progress that this forum has made and making from where it was to where it is now, but what makes a forum buzzing with Q&A .

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Is_the_Key

Answer (score 9):

I think right now it's just a function of the number of users on the site. Programmers is one of the oldest sites on the network whereas we're only just about to graduate from beta and get a nice theme etc.

If you look at the user list on programmers they have 2204 *pages* of users, right now we have 54 ;) I'm confident that this site will continue to grow, and once the beta label and styling has been removed it'll look that bit more attractive to potential users.

Comment: Just interesting: when should it happen (the removal of beta label etc)?

Comment: Not sure — it was mentioned on the StackExchange podcast that we're due to be promoted, but I don't know how long the process takes etc. I expect there'll be some comms with Salesforce involved around branding etc.